# Tracking disk I/O by application in Windows from the cmd

Tags: windows, command-line, disk-analysis

I'm looking for a utility that I could run from cmd on Microsoft Windows and that would display disk I/O by application.

On Linux, I use `iotop`:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can do exactly this, (and more), with [python](http://python.org) and the [psutil](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/psutil) library, there is even an [example](https://github.com/giampaolo/psutil/blob/master/examples/iotop.py) called iotop.py but unfortunately it uses curses which is a problem on Windows less you also install the curses wheel from [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#curses), *I also had to add two lines marked as added on Windows 10*.

- Free, Gratis & Open Source
- Command Line *or you can add a GUI wrapper*
- Cross platform including windows
- You could limit the output to the highest 20 reads/writes
- Logging or graphing readily available

### Example Code *(as modified)*

```
import atexit
import time
import sys
try:
    import curses
except ImportError:
    sys.exit('platform not supported no curses') # Try: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#curses for windows

import psutil


# --- curses stuff
def tear_down():
    win.keypad(0)
    curses.nocbreak()
    curses.echo()
    curses.endwin()

win = curses.initscr()
atexit.register(tear_down)
curses.endwin()
lineno = 0


def print_line(line, highlight=False):
    """A thin wrapper around curses's addstr()."""
    global lineno
    try:
        if highlight:
            line += " " * (win.getmaxyx()[1] - len(line))
            win.addstr(lineno, 0, line, curses.A_REVERSE)
        else:
            win.addstr(lineno, 0, line, 0)
    except curses.error:
        lineno = 0
        win.refresh()
        raise
    else:
        lineno += 1
# --- /curses stuff


def bytes2human(n):
    """
    >>> bytes2human(10000)
    '9.8 K/s'
    >>> bytes2human(100001221)
    '95.4 M/s'
    """
    symbols = ('K', 'M', 'G', 'T', 'P', 'E', 'Z', 'Y')
    prefix = {}
    for i, s in enumerate(symbols):
        prefix[s] = 1 << (i + 1) * 10
    for s in reversed(symbols):
        if n >= prefix[s]:
            value = float(n) / prefix[s]
            return '%.2f %s/s' % (value, s)
    return '%.2f B/s' % (n)


def poll(interval):
    """Calculate IO usage by comparing IO statics before and
    after the interval.
    Return a tuple including all currently running processes
    sorted by IO activity and total disks I/O activity.
    """
    # first get a list of all processes and disk io counters
    procs = [p for p in psutil.process_iter()]
    for p in procs[:]:
        try:
            p._before = p.io_counters()
        except psutil.Error:
            procs.remove(p)
            continue
    disks_before = psutil.disk_io_counters()

    # sleep some time
    time.sleep(interval)

    # then retrieve the same info again
    for p in procs[:]:
        try:
            p._after = p.io_counters()
            p._cmdline = ' '.join(p.cmdline())
            if not p._cmdline:
                p._cmdline = p.name()
            p._username = p.username()
        except (psutil.NoSuchProcess, psutil.ZombieProcess):
            procs.remove(p)
        except (psutil.AccessDenied, ): # Added on Windows 10
            p._username = '????'        # Added on Windows 10
    disks_after = psutil.disk_io_counters()

    # finally calculate results by comparing data before and
    # after the interval
    for p in procs:
        p._read_per_sec = p._after.read_bytes - p._before.read_bytes
        p._write_per_sec = p._after.write_bytes - p._before.write_bytes
        p._total = p._read_per_sec + p._write_per_sec

    disks_read_per_sec = disks_after.read_bytes - disks_before.read_bytes
    disks_write_per_sec = disks_after.write_bytes - disks_before.write_bytes

    # sort processes by total disk IO so that the more intensive
    # ones get listed first
    processes = sorted(procs, key=lambda p: p._total, reverse=True)

    return (processes, disks_read_per_sec, disks_write_per_sec)


def refresh_window(procs, disks_read, disks_write):
    """Print results on screen by using curses."""
    curses.endwin()
    templ = "%-5s %-7s %11s %11s  %s"
    win.erase()

    disks_tot = "Total DISK READ: %s | Total DISK WRITE: %s" \
                % (bytes2human(disks_read), bytes2human(disks_write))
    print_line(disks_tot)

    header = templ % ("PID", "USER", "DISK READ", "DISK WRITE", "COMMAND")
    print_line(header, highlight=True)

    for p in procs:
        line = templ % (
            p.pid,
            p._username[:7],
            bytes2human(p._read_per_sec),
            bytes2human(p._write_per_sec),
            p._cmdline)
        try:
            print_line(line)
        except curses.error:
            break
    win.refresh()


def main():
    try:
        interval = 0
        while True:
            args = poll(interval)
            refresh_window(*args)
            interval = 1
    except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):
        pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```